# How to store the filepath to the video in Android SQlite database and access them?

Tags: database, android-studio, video, android-sqlite, local-storage

I'm creating a gaming application for android which involves videos and other medias to be displayed for each question.I stored my images in drawable folder and accessed them in database, similar way i tried to store the videos in RAW folder and tried to access its not accessing.how can i achieve this?